# Object is still in inactive version

Tags: abap, alv, sap-basis

I have created a basic application to get company details in SAP ABAP with following details.

1. Package Name     : ZSPT_930AM_PKG_1
2. Application Name : ZSPT_930AM_CMPNY_INFO_1
3. Transaction Code : Z39CD
4. Transport Request Number : EC6K900010
5. Sub Request Number       : EC6K900011

I have activated my application and configurations like package, T-Code are also working fine but still when I'm trying to release my transport request I'm getting the below error.
Please find the error in image 5 attached below.

[image: This is my Package]
[image: This is my application, and you can see the status of application is ACTIVE]
[image: Transaction code of my application]
[image: This is my transport request organizer, here my request is EC6K900010]
[image: This is my error]

I have verified all my configurations but still don't where am I going wrong, still It shows object is inactive.
Someone please help me with this.

Comment: This looks very strange, but could you please start transaction SE80? In the navigation on the left side, there is an option: Inactive objects (or something similar, I write this out of my head). Here you have to enter a user name (obviusly your own one) and you get a list of inactive objects under your name and see what is there. Alternatively just make a "not real change" in the program (like add a space in a line and remove it with backspace, than activate the program again and see if it helps

Comment: The `REPT` stands for report texts. Are there any inactive texts in your report?

Comment: Addendum: I just see, you have texts. You use a frame title `TEXT-001`. You can make a doubleclick there and check, if the text was activated.

Comment: Don't confuse your savior name (K**n**ut not Kunt) with [offensive terms](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cunt) :) It's excellent you use that much of screenshots, but it's preferable to post code in code tags, not via screenshots. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error says, that a REPT-object (= report text) is not active.

In your code you use a frame title `TEXT-001`. If you display the program source code via the backend editor (transaction code `SE38`), you find this text element via the menu Goto > Text Elements > Text Symbols:

[image]

There, you have a button or a menu to **activate** your text elements.

---

If you are in the transport (SE01/SE10) you can see all objects in a transport (doubleclick on transport number):
[image]

There you can see the different objects of your transport.

If you position on the `REPT`-text and enter F4 you get a list of all object types (there are many). Some objects are a container for other objects (PROG is a combination of REPS (source code) and REPT (texts), CLASS includes methods, ...)

Comment: I'm sorry Mr Knut It was a typing mistake, thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge.